# How to get all the files in a specific folder?

Tags: powershell

I want to grab all the files from my computer with the word `car` in the filename. I want to grab all the files inside a folder with the foldername `car` too, even when those files doesn't contain car in their filename.

I have wrote the first part, so I can grab all the files from my computer with the word `car`. However I don't know how I can do the second part.

```
Get-ChildItem “C:\” -Recurse -filter *car*  | Copy -Destination  ”C:\Test”
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use *two* [`Get-ChildItem`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-childitem) calls, processing only *files* first, via the `-File` switch, and then only *directories*, using `-Directory`:

```bash
# Files only
Get-ChildItem -File C:\ -Recurse -Filter *car* |
  Copy -Destination C:\Test -WhatIf

# Directories only: for each matching dir.,
# copy its (immediate) files.
Get-ChildItem -Directory C:\ -Recurse -Filter *car* | 
  Get-ChildItem -File |
  Copy -Destination C:\Test -WhatIf
```

<sup>Note: The [`-WhatIf` common parameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_commonparameters#whatif) in the command above *previews* the operation. Remove `-WhatIf`  once you're sure the operation will do what you want.</sup>